# ASP.NET CORE 3 comple for linux

Tags: linux, build, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a question. When I compile as.net core 3 web app with command I get **71** files.
My command is:

**`dotnet publish D:\PortalNekretnine\Beckend\PortalNekretnine.sln --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.0 --output .\build\ --self-contained false --runtime linux-x64 --verbosity quiet`**

That same project if compiled with VS2019 using file **sysytem, framweork-dependent and linux-x64** I got **61** files.

What is the diffrence? Am I doing it the right way when building form command line?

Thnx

Comment: What are the extra files? I made a test with built-in asp.net core 3.0 mvc template, but there is no extra files. Try to share us detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: If I remember right, there was one exta .com file with the same name as the starting dll. I am building a web api.